# Text getting hidden on uitextview when changing font size

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0, uitextview

I am right now restricting the uitextfield length as below:

```
NSString* newText = [textView.text stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:text];

CGSize tallerSize = CGSizeMake(textView.frame.size.width-15,textView.frame.size.height*2);

CGSize newSize = [newText sizeWithFont:textView.font constrainedToSize:tallerSize lineBreakMode:
UILineBreakModeWordWrap];

[textView setSelectedRange:range]; 

if ( newSize.height > 325 )
{
  return NO;
}
else if( newSize.height == 325 && [text isEqualToString:@"\n"] )
{
 return NO;
}
else
return YES;
```

which works fine. But in my application the user can change the text size. If the user types the font in 10px size and types to the total length, and then changes his font size to 30, uitextview hides the texts.

How can I fix this problem? Thanks for any help.

Comment: Why are you trying to restrict the length of the field based on the number of pixels it renders as?

Comment: @kevin: thanks for the reply..can you pls tell then how can irestrict the length of the textfield

Comment: Somebody pls help me out

Answer (score 0):

1)Implement the [UITextFieldDelegate](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITextFieldDelegate_Protocol/UITextFieldDelegate/UITextFieldDelegate.html) protocol

2)Implement the `textField:shouldChangeCharactersInRange:replacementString:` method.

That method gets called on every character tap or previous character replacement. in this method, you can do something like this:

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string {
    if ([textField.text length] > MAXLENGTH) {
        textField.text = [textField.text substringToIndex:MAXLENGTH-1];
        return NO;
    }
    return YES;
}
```